# Prove a fact involving continuous functions and connected spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, connectedness

Let $X$ be a space, then I want to check that $X$ is connected if and only if every continuous $f:X\to Y$ into a discrete space $Y$ is constant.

So I did the following:

$\Rightarrow]$  We suppose that $X$ is connected and we take $f:X \to Y$ continuous and $Y$ discrete, this implies that $f(X)$ is connected, but since $Y$ is discrete $f(X)=\{x_0\}$ (This is because I have the result that a discrete space with at least two points is not connected), therefore $f$ is constant.

$\Leftarrow]$ We take $f:X \to Y$ with $Y$ discrete and $f$ continuous, then by hypothesis we have that $f(X)=\{x_0\}$, **but the thing here is that I don't know how to conclude.**

So Can someone help me with the verification of my proof please, and help me to fix it if I have something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I am presuming that $Y$ contains at least two points $y_1,y_2$.

Suppose $X$ is not connected, then there are two open, disjoint sets $U,V$ such that $X=U \cup V$.

Define $f(x) = y_1$ if $x \in U$ and $f(x)=y_2 $ otherwise. Then it is not hard to show
that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: So that is contrapositive, right ?

Comment: Yes. Or a contradiction, depending on how you start.

Comment: So if I have further questions can I let you know?

Comment: Sure! ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

The first part is correct. For the second part

**Hint:** Do it by absurd. Assume that $f(x)$ contains more than a point. What can you say about the primage of each of the points in the image?

Comment: Ok, let me try that, just give me some time to get  the idea, if I have further questions, can I let you know?

Comment: @user162343 Sure, just leave a comment here below.

Comment: Right :) , I'll do that :)

Comment: @user162343 Oh, damn, I just noticed that my hint is also for solving the first part, not the second one. copper.hat's answer is the good one.

Comment: Ok, jajaja don't worry, so I'll use that answer :), But my first part is well performed right?

Comment: @user162343 Yeah, it's basically equivalent to the method I suggested.